# Знаки препинания в стихотворении Лермонтова "Тамара".

Tags: сравнение, пунктуация

"В той башне, высокой и тесной,  царица Тамара жила: прекрасна, как ангел небесный, как демон, коварна и зла".

Это современная постановка знаков препинания, но отнюдь не единственная, встречаются  следующие варианты: а) оборот "высокой и тесной" не обособляется; б) оба оборота с союзом КАК не обособляются; в) "как ангел небесный" обособляется, а  "как демон" не обособляется.

Вопросы:

а) Каков текст прижизненного издания 1840 года;

б) чем объясняются колебания в постановке знаков препинания, какой вариант следует использовать в современных тестах, нужна ли правка авторской пунктуации?

Comment: Я в деталях не отвечу, но искать какую-то единую, универсальную  систему правописания в текстах, написанных до 1954 г. не стоит, а уж до Грота - просто наивно. Это первое.  
Второе. Поход к переводу на современное правописание был в разное время - а иногда и в одно время у разных издательств - был разным.   
Это просто мысли в тему, понимаю, что на ответ не тянет.  
Представленный вариант явно отражает современный подход в пунктуации.

Comment: Названные варианты разрешены и в современной орфографии, но являются авторскими. Они меняют мелодику текста (расстановку тонических ударений), а для стихотворного произведения это особенно важно. А приведенный вариант - самый простой, обычный, стандартный - может быть, не стоит всё бездумно упрощать, особенно классику. Хорошо еще до Пушкина не добрались: "По дороге зимней, скучной Тройка борзая бежит...", нет обособления.

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что обособление сравнительных оборотов тут "авторское".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все перечисленные варианты пунктуации нормативны.

"Если предшествующее определение выражено местоимением, то последующие определения могут обособляться или не обособляться" в зависимости от степени интонационно-смысловой близости с определяемым существительным (здесь предшествует определение *той*).

"Обороты с союзом *как* не выделяются запятыми, если на первый план выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия (обороты с *как* можно заменить в этих случаях формой творительного падежа существительного или наречием)". То есть постановка запятой зависит от авторского акцента - на сравнении или на образе действия. В этом смысле может быть даже так: "прекрасна, как ангел небесный, как демон коварна и зла" (прекрасна подобно ангелу и демонически коварна).

Не знаю, как было у Лермонтова, но менять авторскую пунктуацию нельзя, даже если она ненормативна. А уж если нормативна - по рукам надавать "подсебяшникам", адаптирующим чужие тексты к своему однобокому знанию пунктуации.

Comment: Согласна с Вашим мнением по поводу авторской пунктуации, немного добавлю по поводу авторского акцента в части интонации. Мне наиболее близок вариант:"В той башне высокой и тесной царица Тамара жила: прекрасна, как ангел небесный, как демон коварна и зла".Обороты с союзом КАК разные по структуре и распространенности, и такая пунктуация обеспечивает тоническое ударение словах "Ангел небесный - коварна и злА", что определяет их противопоставление. Что касается определения "высокой и тесной", то такой вариант часто встречается в поэзии, но он необязательно связан с местоимением "той".

Answer (score 0):

В случае с демоном могу предположить, что здесь отсутствие запятой можно объяснить тем, что сравнительный оборот стоит перед прилагательными "коварна и зла". Если бы было "Коварна и зла, как демон" - отсутствие запятой было бы ошибкой.
"В той башне высокой и тесной" - отсутствие запятой можно объяснить тем, что прилагательное тесно примыкает к определяемому слову. Акцент падает именно на эти слова, а не на "башню".

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, "в той башне высокой и тесной" - здесь, действительно, тесная связь существительного и определений, произношение без паузы. Необособленный вариант встречается в большинстве текстов, обособлять стали только в последнее время.